# change code in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want create status by class,if status=1 result is text "approved" and class "label label-sm label-success" and vice versa.

i have code like this

```
<span class="<?php if( $row->status==0 ) {
          echo 'label label-sm label-warning';
       } else if ( $row->status==1 ) {
          echo 'label label-sm label-info';
       } else { 
          echo 'label label-sm label-success';
 }?>"> 
<?php 
   if ( $row->status == 0 ) {
      echo 'Processing';
   } else if ( $row->status==1 ) { 
      echo 'Waiting';
   } else { 
      echo 'Approved';
   }?></span>
```

how to create code if i have code like above change to javascript by class?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you're asking but if you mean to ask for a simpler way to create the element with the proper text and class, this would work:

```
   <?php
    $vars = $row->status==0 ?  ['warning','Processing'] : ($row->status==1 ? ['info','Waiting'] : ['success','Approved']);
    echo '<span class="label label-sm label-'.$vars[0].'">'.$vars[1].'</span>';
    ?>
```

Comment: please fix, missing `()` `$vars = $status==0 ? ['warning','Processing'] : ( $status==1 ?['info','Waiting'] : ['success','Approved']);` [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) [precedence differ from c](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @cske Indeed, nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out if this is something you want don and just let me know if its correct or you still need modifications

```js
function myStatus(){

if ($(".status").data('status') == '0'){
  $(".status").addClass('label label-sm label-warning').css({'color':'red'})
}else if($(".status").data('status') == '1'){
 $(".status").addClass('label label-sm label-info').css({'color':'yellow'})
}else{
 $(".status").addClass('label label-sm label-success').css({'color':'black'})
}

if ($(".statusb").data('status2') == '0'){
  $(".statusb").addClass('label label-sm label-warning').css({'color':'#333'})
}else if($(".statusb").data('status2') == '1'){
 $(".statusb").addClass('label label-sm label-info').css({'color':'green'})
}else{
 $(".statusb").addClass('label label-sm label-success').css({'color':'orange'})
}

}

myStatus()
```

```css
span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="status1" data-status="insert php echo here ">asd</span>
<span class="status2" data-status2="insert php echo here">asd</span>
<br>
Working Example base on status:
<span class="status" data-status="0">asd</span>
<span class="statusb" data-status2="1">asd</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

1st thing you need a hidden field to store the status field
2nd i think i will remove all the if/else code and let the JS to handels all

So the HTML code will look like this

```
<input type='hidden' id='status' value='<?php echo $row->status?>' />
<span id='targetSpan' class=""> </span>
```

In the js, as the if/else may need to run multiple times, so i write it into a function.

And as the page load, the function should run.  So the JS would look like this:

```
$('#document').ready(function() {
    updateSpanClass(); //call at beginning

    function updateSpanClass(){
        var status = $('#status').val();

        //every call of the function i class the class first
        $('#targetSpan').removeClass();

        if(status == 1){
            $('#targetSpan').addClass('label label-sm label-info'); //update class
            $('#targetSpan').html('Waiting'); //update text
        } else if(status == 0) {
            $('#targetSpan').addClass('label label-sm label-warning');
            $('#targetSpan').html('Processing');
        } else {
            $('#targetSpan').addClass('label label-sm label-success');
            $('#targetSpan').html('Approved');
        }
    }
});
```